# ASP.Net MVC - What is the recommended way to retain form values across different controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, controller

Let's say I have a HomeController which has an Index action, in the Index.cshtml View I will be posting back to an action in another controller (DocumentsController), after the action is completed I redirect back to Home/Index.

What is the recommended/cleanest approach to maintain the form values that the user has submitted in the Index.cshtml view?  Given that it is being redirected from another controller?

EDIT: I'm presently using RedirectToAction:

`return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");`

So using this approach how can I retain form values?

Comment: passing Model among contollres is clean and effective

Comment: So passing route values from my DocumentsController action?

Comment: this will help to some extent..... http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3. the best way is to use model.binder approach to retain the values across post.

Comment: route values are element without concept and meaning we live in world which consisted of objects.objects are like map. by extracting your route values and wrapping them inside an object and passing object to another method or action is the proper way i think.

Comment: I can't pass an object as I'm using RedirectToAction, see my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the data in `TempData` or `Session`, call `RedirectToAction`, and then retrieve the values from `TempData` or `Session` again.

`TempData` is special. It stores stuff in Session, however, the data stored through `TempData` is only kept for the current request and a subsequent request. After that, the data is thrown out. It sounds well-suited for what you need, but if you need the data to stay around longer, just use Session.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
         var someData = TempData["SomeData"] as string; // can be anything, using a string as an example;

         return View(someData);
    }
}

public class DocumentsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult DoSomething()
    {
        TempData["SomeData"] = "Hello, world!";

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

When you first visit `Home/Index`, `"SomeData"` will be missing (null). When you visit `Documents/DoSomething`, it will set `"SomeData"` to a string, then redirect you to `Home/Index`. At that point, `Index` will see the string we placed in `"SomeData"` and you can use it in your `Index` view. *After* that point however, all temp data will be cleared out.

So, for example, if the user refreshed `Index` after the redirect a bunch of times, the temp data would be missing during the refreshes. If that is not acceptable, then don't use TempData, but keep it in the Session instead.

Comment: Thanks for that, I was really just seeking clarification, I should've made it clear that I'm aware of TempData, Session etc. but I was really wondering if I was missing anything :-)